# Partial derivatives of a function in the form $f = f(u,v)$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have completely forgotten how to do partial derivatives of functions with more than one variable. I don't want the answer so here is the gist of the question. I have a function:

$$
f = f(u,v)$$

where $u = (r, \phi)$ and $v = (r, \phi)$ and I need to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$. How do I do this again?

I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the chain rule where you use a formula like

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \cdot \frac{du}{dr} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} \cdot \frac{dv}{dr}.$$

Is this correct?

EDIT: I think the formula should be

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$

but I'm not sure how I would do $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ as $f = f(u,v)$ is the formula they have given for $f$.

Comment: Almost. The differentiation of $u$ and $v$ with respect to $r$ should be partial as well, because they both are functions of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @Marc Edited that in before I saw your comment lol, sorry. How do I do those partial derivatives though?

Comment: Unless you have the rules explicitly, you leave them as they are written. Do you have a specific example in mind?

Comment: @Marc I have to work out the PD to $f = f(u,v)$ where $u = r \cos (\phi)$ and $v = r \sin (\phi)$. So $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$ etc is easy but its the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ bit I'm struggling on.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What you wrote is the partial differential equation for $f$ with respect to $r$. If $f=f(u,v)$ is your known function, then you do have $\partial f / \partial u$ and likewise with $v$. Perhaps to strengthen your belief, consider the case $f(u,v) = 2uv - cos (u^2 -v^2)$ and apply usual polar coordinates as $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @Marc My question basically just says "Work out $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$ for $f = f(u, v) where $u = ..$ and $v = ..$. That's why I wrote the formula for $r$ as I thought that's how I was supposed to work it out, but now I don't know how to do the bit for $u$